# Moving multiple buttons?

Tags: android

Can anyone help me?
I'm having problems with this.
I want buttons to move.
Does anyone have similar problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button[] b = null;
    Intent[] intent=null;
    TranslateAnimation[] trans;
    Typeface font;
    ImageView plavi,ljubicasti;
    AnimationDrawable plavian,ljubicastian;

    int i=0,f=2000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Class[] naslovi = {
                First.class,
                Second.class,
                Third.class,
                Fourth.class,
                Fifth.class};

        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"FatMarker.ttf");
        b = new Button[]
                {
                ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button1),
                ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button2),
                ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button3),
                ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button4),
                ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button5),
                };
        intent = new Intent[b.length];
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {   

            intent[i] = new Intent(MainActivity.this,naslovi[i]);
            b[i].setTag(i);
            b[i].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
                public void onClick(View v)
                    {

                    startActivity(intent[(Integer)v.getTag()]);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading ...",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                 });
            b[i].setTypeface(font);
            trans[i] = new TranslateAnimation( 0, 0, f, 0);
            trans[i].setDuration(f);
            b[i].startAnimation(trans[i]);
            b[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            f=f+250;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have with some fixes...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button[] b = null;
    Intent[] intent=null;
    //TranslateAnimation[] trans; Array of TranslateAnimation?
    TranslateAnimation trans;
    Typeface font;
    ImageView plavi,ljubicasti;
    AnimationDrawable plavian,ljubicastian;

    int i=0,f=2000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        trans = new TranslateAnimation( 0, 0, f, 0);
        Class[] naslovi = {
            First.class,
            Second.class,
            Third.class,
            Fourth.class,
            Fifth.class};

        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"FatMarker.ttf"); 
        b = new Button[]
                {
                ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button1),
                ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button2),
                ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button3),
                ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button4),
                ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.button5),
                };
        intent = new Intent[b.length];
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {   

            intent[i] = new Intent(Main.this,naslovi[i]);
            b[i].setTag(i);
            b[i].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
                public void onClick(View v)
                    {

                    startActivity(intent[(Integer)v.getTag()]);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading ...",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                 });
            b[i].setTypeface(font);   
            //trans[i] = new TranslateAnimation( 0, 0, f, 0);
            //trans[i].setDuration(f);        
            trans.setDuration(f); // Apply animation!
            b[i].startAnimation(trans);
            b[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            f=f+250;
        }
    } 
}
```

the buttons appear from the bottom to the top of the screen.